# “Math paragraphs”: display a lot of small formulas, automatically placing line and page breaks

Tags: equations, paragraphs

I have a lot of short formulas that I want to set out all together—short enough that usually two or three will fit on each line—so I would like to simply give all the formulas, and let TeX place the line- and page-breaks between them.

The `mathpar` environment, from [the `mathpartir` package](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/), provides almost exactly what I want, allowing one to write e.g.

```
\begin{mathpar}
  x = y
\and
  y = z^2
\and
  z = w^3
\end{mathpar}
```

According to the documentation, this is implemented using TeX's usual paragraph mechanism.  However, `mathpar` paragraphs do not break across pages, it seems.  Is there another package/environment similar to this but allowing page-breaks?  Or is there a way to modify `mathpar` to allow them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [package `mathpartir`](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/mathpartir.sty) has an environment `mathparpagebreakable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{document}
\begin{mathparpagebreakable}
  x = y
\and   
  y = z^2
\and
  z = w^3
\end{mathparpagebreakable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much — that’s exactly what I was after!  Confusingly, this seems to have been added since the version number was last bumped — the copy I was using was up-to-date on version number, but didn’t include this environment (and a few other minor changes).

Answer (score 3):

It appears you don't need any special environment at all just use a normal paragraph.

```
 $ x = y$, $y = z^2$ and   $z = w^3$ ....
```

will break over lines and pages where needed.